# Swap Duplicate Redirect

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Is it unethical to say my current employer has financial problems when looking for another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67220/is-it-unethical-to-say-my-current-employer-has-financial-problems-when-looking-f?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Was closed as a duplicate of this, admittedly older, question:

[Can I disclose my company's financial troubles when applying for new jobs (UK)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55404/can-i-disclose-my-companys-financial-troubles-when-applying-for-new-jobs-uk)

But I believe the newer question is much more suited to being redirected to, covers a more general situation and has enjoyed more input thanks to a stint on the HNQ.

I'd like to suggest reopening the the first question and marking the second as a duplicate of the first once that's been done. This can be done by community votes or if there's sufficient consensus here I assume a mod can do so manually.

Comment: I voted to reopen.  3 RO votes as of this comment.

Answer (score -1):

I would Keep both open.

My reasoning behind it the older question has answers relevant to the UK.
Now there might not be a lot of difference with the new questions but alot of the context will be usefull for the UK and might not be for the US.

For example the financial turnover is public knowledge in my home Country as is the threshold**. Referring that in an interview isnt considered a negative or possitive.

However I would have no clue if an American Company has this available or even where I could find this.

** refering the required average weekly incoming

Comment: What's the difference between this question, which is UK-specific vs. general and the one last week that was Germany-specific vs general? Why would you *open* this using the same reason you used to *close* the other one?

Comment: @nvoigt perhaps if you read the question and my answer you would understand. Please don't look up my activity SE, just to fill them with your ignorance.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you. I don't "look up your activity", I remember things. Like the fact you posted an answer to my question right here on the same Stack a few days ago. Please stop insulting me though. That's not nice.

Comment: @nvoigt One I dont open anything, I am merely stateing that keeping both open has value. Two: My reason not to open the other question was since it had no value. Why didnt it have value you ask? Since the core of his question suggests the OP was looking for a valid reason to fire someone without him keeping his benefits. Also the OP ( nor did you) find it important enough to place relevant Information from comments into the qeustion. Three: _I remember things_ that could be, but then again I would assume one would be faster in their Response.

Comment: @nvoigt Four: _PLease stop insulting me though_ That wasnt an Insult, that was me stating that I see the Humor in you not being able to take your loss. If that wasnt the case then I take my comment back, though if that is the case please do explain why you dont see my case here as right compared to yours and removeing your downvote.

Comment: Your assumption is probably based on the assumption that I read this answer here as soon as you posted it. I did not. I read it a few minutes before I commented on it.

Comment: I downvoted this answer here because I value *consistency* over my own personal opinion. If we close specific questions as duplicate of very broad generic answers, then we should do it *consistently* for **all** of them. Last time we closed specific in favor of generic, so this time we should close specific in favor of generic, too.

Comment: "Since the core of his question suggests the OP was looking for a valid reason to fire someone without him keeping his benefits." I guess arguing over that past question is pointless, we seem to have read two very different questions or have a very different perception of what is normally allowed and/or tolerated in Germany.

Comment: @nvoigt which is complete BS since the OP didnt ask that. If he did I would agree to open if. I also value consistency however These questions are nothing alike and should thus be treated as such. Also your downvote is nothing, but a silly _driveby vote_ and as such I would once again ask you to remove it. _I guess arguing over that past question is pointless_ Please do explain why you keep provoking people to start it again?

Comment: Why would I remove my downvote? I do not agree with the position you have stated in your answer. So I downvoted it. This is meta, this is how meta works. I would prefer you to stop calling it "silly" or "ignorance".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47868/discussion-between-raoul-mensink-and-nvoigt).